# How to avoid protected member fields in inheritance in C++?

Tags: c++

I know protected member fields is anti pattern in C++, but in the following code, I'm struggling to find a way to avoid protected usage in `Base` class. Or should I not use inheritance at all here? If so, what can I replace the architecture with ?

```
   class Base {
 public:
    Base(int a, int b, int c): a_(a), b_(b), c_(c) {
      setDerived();
    };
   virtual ~Base() = delete;
   
   virtual void setDerived(){
     derived_ = someFuncAInAnotherNameSpace(a_, b_, c_);
   };

   virtual bool shouldOperate(){
     return someFuncBInAnotherNameSpace(a_, b_, c_);
   };


   void operate(){
     if shouldOperate(){
       _myObj.operate(derived_);
     }
    }
  
 protected:   
    int a_;
    int b_;
    int c_;
    int derived_;

  private:
    MyClass _myObj;
};

class Child : public Base {
 public:
    Child(int a, int b, int c): Base(a,b,c) {}

  void setDerived() override {
     derived_ = DifferentFuncInAnotherNameSpace(a_, b_, c_);
   };

  bool shouldOperate() override {
     return AnotherDifferentFuncInAnotherNameSpace(a_, b_, c_);
   };
};
```

Comment: Do you realize that the call to `setDerived` in `Base`'s constructor will never call a sub-`class`'s implementation?

Comment: One easy fix would be to add accessor-methods like `int GetA() const {return a_;}` to your `Base` class.  Those methods can be either `protected` or `public`, and the child class can call them when necessary to get the values it needs (while the base class can still rest assured that the child class won't/can't change the member-variables' values)

Comment: @StephenNewell how can that be fixed then ?

Comment: The base constructor runs before the derived constructor, so derived doesn't exist yet. You can do it in the derived class's constructor, but that means you need to expose `derived_` one way or another. That or use two-phase construction, and I think that's a bit of a waste here. Count the number of hoops you have to jump through to avoid something generally considered bad. If the hoop count starts getting annoying you may have a specific case where it's exactly what you need.

Comment: You write (abridged): "`int a_; int b_; int c_; DifferentFuncInAnotherNameSpace();` should I use inheritance here?" How the heck should we know based on this information? There is not a slightest hint of what the hierarchy is actually supposed to do. Please describe your real life scenario.